# How to use std::cout with my (templated) class?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to overload the `<<` operator, to print out a class instance to the console like this:

```
std::cout << instance << std::endl;
```

I've found a solution here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

But I cannot use it, because my class is templated:

```
template<typename T>
myClass {
    //code...
};
```

---

**Edit:**
I get an error, if I try to define it inside the class body: `it must take only one argument`

Comment: In a member function you conceptually have a hidden `this` as an extra parameter. Here the first argument to `operator<<` has to be `std::ostream&`, so it *could* possibly be a member of the stream class. As it is not, you have to make it a free function (non-member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (adapt it to your code):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
    // write obj to stream
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I get an error, if I try to define it inside the class body: `it must take only one argument`

Comment: You can put it outside the class definition. Try and let me know if it works. Something like: 

`template<typename T>
myClass {
    //code...
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
    // write obj to stream
    return os;
}
`

Comment: Yes, it works if I change the name of the template parameters

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can use the example, just adapt it for your template.

Instead of

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
```

you would need

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const myClass<T>& dt)
```